# Python threads and request module

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, http, request, queue

I have a requirement to prepare a python script to login to a SOAP interface, run large amount queries using threads, then logout of the SOAP interface.

I have prepared the code it can do below
1. Login to the service for each thread
2. Run the queries

However when I start to send logout using simple request.post method, it does not seem to work most of the time. The sessions left hanging in the server. Any ideas why this is happening. Do I need to use some sort of sessions to bind login and logout sessions together

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved. Used combination of Queue, multiprocessing and requests to get this working. Seems issues with threads and requests